# Is there a way to reference other defined colors in a SwiftUI Color Set?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have a set of predefined theme colors (think `Red1`, `Red2`, `Blue1`, `Blue2`, etc) defined as Color Sets (using Any Appearance) in my app's assets. I want to create some other Color Sets that have dark / light variations that use those pre-defined colors, ie `CustomColor` would be `Blue1` in light mode and `Blue2` in dark mode. Is there a way for CustomColor to reference the existing Blue1 or Blue2 definitions?

This is to avoid redefining my color values several times. I'm hoping that I can avoid entering the same value into multiple Color Sets in the Color Set editor, and instead have a single Color Set defining that color that can be referenced by other Color Sets, so for instance, if my designer decides that our Blue1 color should change from `#0000ff` to `#0000fe` I can update it in just one Color Set instead of several.

System colors can be easily referenced via the color editor in Xcode but I don't see any way to reference my own colors.

Comment: You really have got to give us something here. How have you defined them?

Comment: If you create Color Set in Assets you can have a single color in code that will adapt with the scene

Comment: @Yrb updated it to hopefully be clearer. I want to use Color Sets in assets for all of these colors, I just want to be able to reference a color from another color set.

Comment: @loremipsum is correct. That is what the asset catalog is for.